# Chrome disable security warning for Intranet sites

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I have a site in my internal network that has a valid certificate for it's external hostname (blabla.example.com). But when I access it from my LAN I use it's IP address to connect to it and Chrome emits a warning due to the fact the hostname is different than the one used in the certificate. How can I disable this warning for this site or, preferentially for my whole LAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acces your site via the external name. for this you have to adjust your dns-resolver to provide the internal ip of your blabla.example.com. since you are a great admin you are able to achieve this :)

(to answer that 2nd part seriously you would have to provide more information about your network-topology or you could search http://serverfault.com)

Comment: I'm not in control of the network, unfortunately (I share infrastructure with a few other companies). My external DNS resolves for another computer that does the port forwarding. I could start running a DNS server, though.

Comment: for your own machine you could also go the short-route and set an entry to your `/etc/hosts` or the windows equivalent `C:\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` .. look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)