# How do I disable the "This is probably not the site that you are looking for!" warning in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the warning Chrome gives if a security certificate is not trusted?](https://superuser.com/questions/27268/how-do-i-disable-the-warning-chrome-gives-if-a-security-certificate-is-not-trust)

I have to regularly browse to a site where the SSL certificate appears to be misconfigured and every time I do I have to click through a "This is probably not the site that you are looking for!" warning due to a name mismatch. I have added the certificate to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities so it wouldn't display a different error screen saying the certificate wasn't trusted.

How can I disable this dialog so I don't have to click through each time I visit the site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable the warning Chrome gives if a security certificate is not trusted?](http://superuser.com/questions/27268/how-do-i-disable-the-warning-chrome-gives-if-a-security-certificate-is-not-trust) also, http://superuser.com/questions/206641/chrome-disable-security-warning-for-intranet-sites?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/213539/can-i-disable-certificate-error-warning-in-firefox-chrome-internet-explorer?rq=1

Comment: So it's not any of those. I have already imported the certificate so it is trusted and before the certificate was imported I was getting a different error so that is not the issue. It's a very badly set up certificate so that rather than the domain name http://www.example.com it merely has Example so there is no way I can change the way I access the site to correct the conflict.

Comment: On some [citation needed] websites, Chrome will ignore your attempts to trust a website if the SSL certificate is self-signed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm using a self signed certificate for a predefined domain name on my own host. But I am always prompted because the name doesn't match. I do not care about the name and would prefer to add an exception. I have not figured out how (or if it is possible) yet.

Comment: This question is marked incorrectly. It’s not a duplicate of the first question that @techie007 linked which is a different warning message. The second link is a more specialized situation (using IP addresses when you can’t access DNS), and the third question is too vague.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. We're talking about two different Chrome security warnings.